# "Gradle Task Dependency Issue: Task ':cloud_firestore:packageDebugAssets' not found, needing dependency on ':app:compileDebugShaders'"

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dependencies, cloud

My code is fine and there are no errors but after debugging i got this error

```
 What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':cloud_firestore:packageDebugAssets' (type 'MergeSourceSetFolders').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Convo\convo\build\convo\intermediates\shader_assets\debug\out'.

    Reason: Task ':cloud_firestore:packageDebugAssets' uses this output of task ':app:compileDebugShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':app:compileDebugShaders' as an input of ':cloud_firestore:packageDebugAssets'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:compileDebugShaders' from ':cloud_firestore:packageDebugAssets' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:compileDebugShaders' from ':cloud_firestore:packageDebugAssets' using Task#mustRunAfter.
```

Help me with this

i tried changing build.gradle dependencies but the result is same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.